# Asking for reference to mathematicians, not books -- off-topic?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

Is my question here:

[Categorical axiomatization of projective spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942137/categorical-axiomatization-of-projective-space-looking-for-supervisor)

off-topic? If yes, where would be a good place to post it?

Comment: After your edit I have voted to reopen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mainly it is off-topic as "seeking personal advice."

There is not really a place to ask it. A part that might be on-topic is to ask for recent work on such problems, which is a mathematical question, and related who is working on this now.

To see if somebody could and is willing to supervise your work specifically is a question that you would have to sort out via direct correspondence.